# where are the "external" JAR's?

Tags: netbeans, ant, ide, build, package

Where is the lib folder with the JAR's?  Is there some magic to load the JAR's from another directory?

**Specifically, where is beansbinding-1.2.1.jar and the other jar is swing-layout-1.0.4.jar?**

image
[image]

directory structure:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ tree fud/
fud/
├── build.xml
├── manifest.mf
├── nbproject
│   ├── build-impl.xml
│   ├── genfiles.properties
│   ├── private
│   │   ├── private.properties
│   │   └── private.xml
│   ├── project.properties
│   └── project.xml
└── src
    └── dur
        └── bounceme
            └── net
                └── view
                    ├── NewJFrame.form
                    └── NewJFrame.java

7 directories, 10 files
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ head fud/build.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- You may freely edit this file. See commented blocks below for -->
<!-- some examples of how to customize the build. -->
<!-- (If you delete it and reopen the project it will be recreated.) -->
<!-- By default, only the Clean and Build commands use this build script. -->
<!-- Commands such as Run, Debug, and Test only use this build script if -->
<!-- the Compile on Save feature is turned off for the project. -->
<!-- You can turn off the Compile on Save (or Deploy on Save) setting -->
<!-- in the project's Project Properties dialog box.-->
<project name="fud" default="default" basedir=".">
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an option of add Jar/Folder just below Add Library . Use that

Comment: Oh, my question must be unclear, unfortunately.  What I mean is, there are already two JAR's in the library folder but I cannot find them in the directory structure.  I will update my question.

Comment: both of them are showing already there , right ? they will not be shown in tree as I feel they are placed outside the project and you have just added them externally

Comment: ok, thank you.  can you explain what you mean by "add externally"?  I was able to add a jar and will show that in a sec, but, I suppose, my question is, if they're added externally, what does that mean and where are they?

Comment: externally meaning not existing in your project , and you want to use them in your project so you add them by using Add Jar/Folder , which means, they will not be existing physically in your folder , but will act as if they are in the same folder

Comment: Ok, I'm going to have to google that, thank you.  Is that done through build.xml perhaps?

Comment: via build.xml and local.properties

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, I got the following structure:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ tree fud/
fud/
├── build.xml
├── lib
│   ├── beans-binding
│   │   ├── beansbinding-1.2.1-doc.zip
│   │   └── beansbinding-1.2.1.jar
│   ├── CopyLibs
│   │   └── org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
│   ├── nblibraries.properties
│   └── swing-layout
│       ├── swing-layout-1.0.4-doc.zip
│       ├── swing-layout-1.0.4.jar
│       └── swing-layout-1.0.4-src.zip
├── manifest.mf
├── nbproject
│   ├── build-impl.xml
│   ├── genfiles.properties
│   ├── private
│   │   ├── config.properties
│   │   ├── private.properties
│   │   └── private.xml
│   ├── project.properties
│   └── project.xml
└── src
    └── dur
        └── bounceme
            └── net
                └── view
                    ├── NewJFrame.form
                    └── NewJFrame.java

11 directories, 18 files
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$
```

by clicking on the project properties as so:

[image]

but don't understand where this JAR's were **before**.